# the solution to $x^2=49+k\cdot12288$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have computed

$x^2=49+k\cdot12288$ for $k=0$ to an arbitrarily large integer and found  $x$ has an integer solution only for $k=0$.

Can someone proove that for $x^2=49+k\cdot12288$,  $x$ has only an integer solution if $k=0$?
Thank you.

Comment: How did you compute this to an arbitrarily large integer ?

Comment: I wrote a C program and checked if x is an integer for every value of k.

Comment: I have checked until k*12288 reached 2^32-1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true, check this pair
$$
x = 4103, k=1370
$$
In fact
$$
(x-7)(x+7) = 2^{12}\cdot3\cdot k
$$
So if $(2^{12}\cdot3)\mid (x^2-49)$ then you have a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $x^2-49=3\cdot 2^{12}\cdot k=(x+7)(x-7)$

You are therefore looking for two factors which differ by $14$, only one of which can be divisible by a power of $2$ greater than $2^1$ (and both must be even).

So the equation has a solution if you can solve $2^{11}r=2s\pm 14$ with one of $r,s$ divisible by $3$ so that $rs=3k$ and the factors are $2^{11}r$ and $2s$.

So, for example, put $r=3$ and $s=3\cdot 2^{10}-7$ and that will lead to a solution.

In fact it is easy to see that whatever value you choose for $r$, you will find a value for $s$. You can force $r$ ro be a multiple of $3$, but will need to check whether $s$  can be a multiple of $3$.